# Power BI matrix row level aggregations

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis

Please I have 2 row levels on my matrix visual and I am trying to modify the aggregation of the first row

level to show average of the data on the second level. please find picture below.

any assistance will be appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snpb7.png)

Answer (score 1):

In the list of Values fields in the matrix, right click `Total Days present (Att)` and change the aggregation from `Sum` to `Average`:

[image]

And at group level (and total level) you will see averages:

[image]

For more information take a look at [Work with aggregates (sum, average, and so on) in the Power BI service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-aggregates) article.

Comment: Hello Andrew, 

Thank you for the response, but my values are percentage in a measure i created and i would like it to show the average of the second row level on the first level.

I tried creating a quick measure using the averagex formular but the results do not make sense.

Thank you in advance for your response.